# Use variable to indicate index range

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a list containing indices that would be used to get elements from another list.

A simple case:

```
A = [5,6,7,8,9,10]    
b = 2:4
```

I want to then do something like

```
C = A[b]
```

Which would be like saying C = A[2:4]

I want to later extend this to multidimensional arrays, where e.g b = [2:4, 5:6] and I can simply call A[b] to extract a multidimensional array out of A.

Answer (score 29):

You can define `b` as a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object to achieve this:

```
In[9]:
A = [5,6,7,8,9,10]    
b = slice(2,4)
A[b]

Out[9]: [7, 8]
```

Regarding your other requirement I think if you create a list object containing 2 `slice` objects then it should achieve what you want:

```
In[18]:
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
b = [slice(1,3), slice(3,4)]
a[b]

Out[18]: 
array([[13],
       [23]])
```

Comment: The second case would be a bit closer to `A[1:3, 3:4]` if `b` is a tuple instead of a list. There may be types that react different when indexed with a list.

Comment: @BlackJack indexing with a list using a list of `slices`s won't work in this case but the OP didn't present an example so I assumed a np array

Answer (score 15):

You can either use straight python using e.g. slice:

```
>>> A = [5,6,7,8,9,10]    
>>> b = slice(2,4)
>>> A[b]
[7, 8]
```

But this does not scale very well to nd-arrays. To do this, I'd recommend using numpy's [`np.s_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html#numpy.s_) function which does exactly what you are looking for, without the need of explicitly constructing a `slice` for each axis.

```
>>> b = np.s_[2:4]
>>> A[b]
[7, 8]
```

This extends nicely to e.g. 2d arrays:

```
>>> A = np.ones(10, 10)
>>> b = np.s_[2:4, 5:6]
>>> A[b]
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

Comment: Is it possible to change a slice? For example  b = np.s_[2:4], b = b - 1.